# logging inbound and outbound HTTP(S) service traffic

Tags: logging, service, kubernetes

How would one begin setting up verbose (headers, body, status_code, etc) logging of all inbound and outbound HTTP traffic to K8s [services](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, body is kind of excessive, but I think that for a state of the art solution, what you're looking for is tracing. Take a peek at [OpenTracing](http://opentracing.io/) and [Jaeger](https://github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger) which are solid CNCF backed choices. You can use things like [Istio](https://istio.io) or [Linkerd](https://linkerd.io) to help feeding tracing solution like Jaeger as well.